# Arduino Sdcard database Library

Tags: sd-card, datalogging

Im using Arduino connected to an SD card and PIR sensor , and based on the inputs from the PIR sensor the data needs to be written on the sd card , It is done , but for retrieving the data from the SD card is there any library for arduino ? Ive seen Extended Database library ,since im retieving huge amount of data from the SD card and i should be able to do Lots of sorting operations based on the CSV values in the file , So can i do Sorting operations in  Extended Database library from an Sd card ive seen the Examples but it doesnt have any sorting operations ,Is Querying data from the SD card using this library is Possible ?ie)Selecting data Based on some Conditions even if it can be done is there any tutorial ? Or is there any other alternative Library? for this purpose . Thank You

Comment: When you are reading the data are you reading it on a PC or Arduino?  If its a PC, you are asking the wrong forum.  If its on an Arduino how are you going to load 32GB of data into 32kB of memory?

Comment: @Matt  No im loading the data from SD card into arduino that too after sorting and selecting a particular record and loading it into arduino